# what is meaning of axis=1 in pandas sort_values function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following code of snippet.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'B', np.nan, 'D', 'C'],
                   'col2' : [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4],
                   'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3]})
print(df)
sorted=df.sort_values(by=1,axis=1)
print(sorted)
```

[image]

The above data is original dataframe .

[image]

The above one is output of the df.sort_values() function.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: What do pandas docs say regarding this?

Comment: They did not provide any example for axis in this context.

Comment: axis=0 means rearrange the rows and axis=1 means rearrange the columns. by=1 tells the columns should be reorderedby row 1. So if you check the output you will see that row 1 is now in increasing order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter `axis=1` refer to columns, while 0 refers to rows. In this case you are sorting by columns, specifically index 1, which is `col2` (indexing in python starts at 0).

Some good examples here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: How are you so sure that col2 is index for df?

Comment: @mad_ Didn't mean for it to sound like col2 is the index, the DataFrame has an actual index. Just meant that for the columns here as `['col1', 'col2', 'col3']`, `'col2'` is at position 1.